# Using a vnc client through ssh tunnel

Tags: macos, ssh, vnc, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Laptop(osx-home network)------>Host1(linux-pc-college network)---->Host2(linux-pc-using vncserver on port 5901, can only be accessed from host1)

I can access host2 through ssh using:

- [user@laptop ~]$ ssh  user1@host1
- [user1@host1 ~]$ ssh  user2@host2

I need to access host2 vncserver using a ssh tunnel from "laptop". Any recommendation, also, which vnclient is suitable for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several options are available. First you need to setup a TCP tunnel.

If the port forwarding to the local network is not disabled in the sshd_conf at host 1, then this would be enough:

> ssh -t -L 5901:*ip-of-host2*:5901 user@Host1

Otherwise you need to build a chain of port forwardings:

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:15901 user1@Host1 ssh -L 15901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@host2
```

if the password authentication is used to connect to host2 then add a `-t` option to the first `ssh`:

```
ssh -t -L 5901:127.0.0.1:15901 user1@Host1 ssh -L 15901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@host2
```

Then use `vncviewer` of your choice to connect to the display `localhost:1`. I prefer to use TigerVNC.

Comment: Thanks @serge that worked. Now I just need to config vncserver. It displays file manager windows like this:http://i.imgur.com/wns0q.jpg

Comment: I don't know why. I have no experience with Mac